# Symfony 1.4 ghost user - current user changes to different user

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I have the following code to display the currently logged in user in my application. The strange thing is intermittantly on odd occasions while the user is browsing from one page to another the username of the logged in user changes to another user who is in the database. Logging out and logging back in then displays the current username.

```
 <? if ($sf_user->isAuthenticated()){?>
  <div id="welcome">
   You are signed in as <strong><?php echo sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->
   getGuardUser()->getName()?></strong> <a href="/logout" class="button">Logout</a>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 <? } ?>
```

Any ideas what could be causing thing?

I can confirm both users were logged in on the same day but at different locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$sf_user` in your views instead `sfContext`

Like:

```
<? if ($sf_user->isAuthenticated()){?>
       <div id="welcome">
              You are signed in as <strong><?php echo $sf_user->getName()?></strong> <a href="/logout" class="button">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, will using $sf_user stop the issue from occuring, if so why?

Comment: The sfContext is the whole app object, sfUser (the $sf_user in views) is reffered to current user session.

Comment: @Wilq Must read: [Why sfContext::getInstance() Is Bad](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/) and if this answer solve your problem, do not forget to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/182741).

Comment: Using `$sf_user` is best practice but why should it resolve the problem? Looking at the `sfContext` class you can see that the `filterTemplateParameters` function get the `$sf_user` parameter from `$this->factories['user']`, exactly like the `getUser` function.